Odd behaviour dragging and dropping in PyQ6 QTableWidget
I'm seeing an odd behaviour with dragging and dropping a row within a QTableWidget. The code below is taken from this question.
When a row is dragged to between two rows, the drop indicator line can either be right at the bottom of the upper row or right at the top of the lower row. Seeing the drop indicator between two rows implies that the dropped row will be between those two rows, but that's not always the case.
See the image below. On the left, if the mouse button is released the dropped row will be above the Red row. On the right, it will be below the Red row.

As the dragged row is moved up and down, the drop indicator moves as described above. The difference is very subtle, maybe just a couple of pixels.
Is there a way to stop this and simply have one position for the drop indicator that represents where the dropped row will appear?
Code:
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QTableWidget,
    QAbstractItemView,
    QTableWidgetItem,
    QWidget,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QApplication,
)


class TableWidgetDragRows(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)

        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectionBehavior.SelectRows)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDropMode.InternalMove)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() == self:
            rows = set([mi.row() for mi in self.selectedIndexes()])
            targetRow = self.indexAt(event.position().toPoint()).row()
            rows.discard(targetRow)
            rows = sorted(rows)
            if not rows:
                return
            if targetRow == -1:
                targetRow = self.rowCount()
            for _ in range(len(rows)):
                self.insertRow(targetRow)
            rowMapping = dict()  # Src row to target row.
            for idx, row in enumerate(rows):
                if row < targetRow:
                    rowMapping[row] = targetRow + idx
                else:
                    rowMapping[row + len(rows)] = targetRow + idx
            colCount = self.columnCount()
            for srcRow, tgtRow in sorted(rowMapping.items()):
                for col in range(0, colCount):
                    self.setItem(tgtRow, col, self.takeItem(srcRow, col))
            for row in reversed(sorted(rowMapping.keys())):
                self.removeRow(row)
            event.accept()
            return


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.table_widget = TableWidgetDragRows()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)

        # setup table widget
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Type", "Name"])

        items = [
            ("Red", "Toyota"),
            ("Blue", "RV"),
            ("Green", "Beetle"),
            ("Silver", "Chevy"),
            ("Black", "BMW"),
        ]
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(len(items))
        for i, (color, model) in enumerate(items):
            self.table_widget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(color))
            self.table_widget.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(model))

        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


"the drop indicator between two rows implies that the dropped row will be between those two rows, but that's not always the case". That's because the dropEvent() in those answers is poorly implemented: indexAt() always gives the position of the index under the mouse, you then need to use dropIndicatorPosition() to know if the actual target is above or below that index, which, in your case, would be targetRow + 1 for BelowItem.

Fabulous, thank you so much.

You're welcome. I suggest you to answer your own question by clicking the related button, with a brief explanation of the problem and how you fixed it, and including a code excerpt or MRE to demonstrate your solution.

Just remove self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False). See this.

Thanks to @musicamante for the pointer.
Here's the change to the linked code to fix this:
targetRow = self.indexAt(event.position().toPoint()).row()
if self.dropIndicatorPosition() == QAbstractItemView.DropIndicatorPosition.BelowItem:
    targetRow += 1
rows.discard(targetRow)

In my app, I am using a QSortFilterProxyModel so the fix is slightly more complex:
to_index = self.indexAt(event.position().toPoint())
if (
    self.dropIndicatorPosition()
    == QAbstractItemView.DropIndicatorPosition.BelowItem
):
    proxy_index = self.proxy_model.createIndex(
        to_index.row() + 1,
        to_index.column(),
        to_index.internalId(),
    )
else:
    proxy_index = to_index
target_row = self.proxy_model.mapToSource(proxy_index).row()


The proxy part seems unnecessary and/or inconsistent: 1. if you want to get the index in the next row, you should just use QModelIndex.siblingAtRow(); 2. you should prefer index() and avoid createIndex() along with the internalId() unless you're completely sure about its behavior; 3. in your original question you ask about QTableWidget which doesn't allow proxies, are you actually using a QTableView? 4. even if you are, the view should always act on its own model, not the source of its proxy.
